# window.location.href.split('/').pop() returning special characters instead of actual value

Tags: javascript

I have the following url:

```
gr-dev.indegene.com/el-gr/ο-πόνος/τι-είναι-ο-πόνος;
```

The problem is when i do:

```
window.location.href.split('/').pop()
```

I get a bunch of special characters , such as the below:

```
"%CF%84%CE%B9-%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%B9-%CE%BF-%CF%80%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82;"
```

I just want to get `τι-είναι-ο-πόνος` instead of the above , how do i do that ?

Comment: `I get a bunch of special characters` - no, they look like the characters you should be getting

Comment: Use window.decodeURI(),

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks can you elaborate ?

Comment: @JaromandaX, how come this works fine , with the english language and not foreign languages ?

Comment: because computer languages are naturally biased towards the spoken language of their creators ... i.e. English

Answer (score 8):

Use the below code.

```
window.decodeURI(window.location.href.split('/').pop());
```

Please refer to [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

```js
 var decodedVal = window.decodeURI("%CF%84%CE%B9-%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%B9-%CE%BF-%CF%80%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82;");
 
 console.log(decodedVal);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the correct value. With one problem, you are getting the encoding version of this value. So you need to decode.

You can do that like:

```
window.decodeURI(window.location.href.split('/').pop())
```

to get the decoded version of the string.

More Info:

URLs only uses specific allowed characters like alphabetic characters, numerals and a few special characters that have a meaning in the URL string. So, any other character should be encoded so that they don't cause problems.

The string `τι-είναι-ο-πόνος` is not a normal character, so is treated as a special character, because of that needs to be encoding to `"%CF%84%CE%B9-%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%B9-%CE%BF-%CF%80%CF%8C%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82;"`

So to get back the original string you need to decode as shown above